Issue in importing header files from local package
In my project I have a local package just for example:
  ABCorePackage - ObjCSources 
                 - include 
                   - Maths.h (symlink) 
                 - ABCore 
                     - Maths.h 
                     - Maths.m 
                 - Package.Swift 

In the project where I am integrating this local package, I have an objective C class ViewController.h, in this class when I add import statement like this import "Maths.h", it is throwing compilation error 'Maths.h' file not found.
However if I change access of file ViewController.h to project, then it works fine.
Please note that I need to keep class ViewController.h as public as I need to add it to Umbrella Header as it is also used in Swift file.
I tried importing the file in umbrella header with #import <ABCorePackage/Maths.h>
